# Migrating PostgreSql to Oracle, handling CITEXT datatype

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle11g

I have an application that was built initially with PostgreSql in mind. In due course, we now have requirement to also support Oracle. I am using Liquibase for DB versioning and Hibernate ORM tool. Some of the columns in the PostgreSql schema have CITEXT datatype. What would it need to have the same feature at database end, without making any code changes, to achieve something similar to what CITEXT provides. And, I understand here I will have to use VARCHAR2(xx) in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CITEXT` simply runs `lower()` before comparisons;

1. You can do what the documentation says by implicitly wrapping `lower()` but that's verbose and inherently unsafe.
2. Add a [TRIGGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/create_trigger.htm) to store text in lowercase, but your still compelled to keep your static strings lowercase.
3. Both Oracle and PostgreSQL support the creation of operators. If your SQL needs to be the same for both engines you can define a new [Oracle OPERATOR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6004.htm) and [PostgreSQL OPERATOR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createoperator.html). This also comes with the caviet that your SQL will become either less portable or have unexpected results on other databases that don't understand your operators.
4. You may temporarily change the environment of Oracle in a session with `alter session set nls_comp=ansi;` which will compare everything as lowercase.

Comment: `nls_comp=ansi` will **not** make the comparison case-insensitive. You probably mean `nls_comp=Linguistic` together with e.g. `nls_sort = BINARY_CI`